# C++ <mysql/mysql.h> how to include it?

Tags: mysql, c

So.

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  MYSQL mysql;
  MYSQL_ROW row;
  MYSQL_RES *result;

  unsigned int num_fields;
  unsigned int i;
  mysql_init(&mysql);
  if (!mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","kevin","****","my_db",0,NULL,0))
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to database: Error: %s\n",
      mysql_error(&mysql));
  }
  else {
   if(mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT * FROM my_table"));
     //here goes the error message <!-- s:o --><img src=\"{SMILIES_PATH}/icon_surprised.gif\" alt=\":o\" title=\"Surprised\"><!-- s:o -->)
   else {
     result = mysql_store_result(&mysql);
     num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
     while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
     {
        unsigned long *lengths;
        lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
        for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
        {
            printf("[%.*s] \t", (int) lengths[i], row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
        } 
        printf("\n");
     }
   }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

That is my code. But I it keeps giving me this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: changedatamysql, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 20.9.2014 16:51:51.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Release\changedatamysql.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  changedatamysql.cpp
1>changedatamysql.cpp(1): warning C4627: '#include <mysql/mysql.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>changedatamysql.cpp(37): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.52
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

So what's up with this?
Im trying to make it so that this program would send data to my mysql data base tables.
So I could read it from my localhost/index okay?
Tutorials, anything to help me is welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is made to build with *pre-compiled headers*, that means that some common headers are kind of pre-compiled into a form that is quicker to read for the compiler, saving compilation time.

However, there is a caveat: The line

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

***must*** be the first non-comment, non-empty line in your source files.

Comment: Okay, I added the #includes to the header and the #include "stdafx.h" to before int main. -> Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
1>

Comment: @Jackdpkevin That is because you probably haven't set up your project setting to tell the compiler where to find the MySQL header files. I don't have Visual Studio myself, so I don't know where it's done, you look for something like "Preprocessor settings" or similar, there should be a setting to add paths that the preprocessor will look for header files.

Comment: Thank you. Will do that!